# Introduce Void Between Shapes / Dissolve Edges

Tags: inkscape

Given this image of a jigsaw with 4 pieces, is there a technique to alter the shapes so they shrink away from each other but retain their interlocking nature?

[image: 2x2 jigsaw puzzle]

I would describe it as dissolving or receding the edges, or adding a tolerance between the pieces.

Bumping up the stroke width gives me the visual result of creating a void between the pieces, but I'm looking to actually alter the underlying shapes.  Ideally looking for a technique that will scale with more pieces.

EDIT: Just in case the SVG is not well visible in your browser, here's a screenshot of the image. The fill colors are selected randomly:

[image]

Comment: You talking about offset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Set a suitably wide stroke on all the shapes
2. Convert the strokes to paths
3. Break apart
4. Fill the parts you want with any colour or add a stroke if required

and obviously delete the leftover black filled paths if you don't want them.

[image]

Another alternative method is to select all the shapes, remove all strokes and use Path > Inset or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>(</kbd> several times, until you get the inset you want. It seems to not create so many nodes.

[image: enterimage description here]

Comment: Pros: Achieves desired result, technique is simple to implement, and should scale to more pieces easy enough.  Cons: Each piece goes from 16 nodes to 30-33, edges lose straightness at some intersections.

Comment: @Todd, I hear you.  I suppose you could remove all strokes and use Path> Inset or `CTRL`+`(`several times, until you get the inset you want.  It seems to not create so many nodes. [see this example](https://imgur.com/a/xHlfF)

Comment: I'm definitely favoring the Path>Inset technique for my particular workflow.  It should scale to more pieces easier and does result in fewer nodes being created.  Each piece goes from 16 nodes to 23-25.  Thank you!  Do you want to create another answer/edit this answer to include that?  Or should I just accept this answer as-is?

Comment: @Todd I've added the Path Inset method to my answer.